# Add New Android Project in Existing Xamarin Forms Project[IOS]

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have an existing Xamarin Forms app that's setup to build for iOS only. Now I want to add a android project in this exiting project to see how the app performs on Android.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (16.10.4)

So The steps I have followed are:

- Created a new separate Xamarin forms solution with Existing project name in just Android.
- Copied Android project folder in to my existing Xamarin folder so I have a .Android and .iOS project in there.
- Add existing android project in my solution and add reference to my new android project.
- Update Nuget packages with same iOS version
- Deleted obj and bin folders from all projects
- Clean & Rebuild

### Error occur as: resource style/MainTheme.Base (aka com.companyname.sampleproject:style/MainTheme.Base) not found.

Error: failed linking references.   sampleproject.Android

Comment: Create a file new xamarin forms app and compare the android project with the one you created

Answer (score 0):

In your android project go to Resources > values > style.xaml file. Here you'll see style like below.

`<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Then go to project `MainActivity.cs` and set your style `Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Base"`